# How to set height for owner draw variable CListBox (MFC)

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, listbox, ownerdrawn

I have a variable-height owner draw ListBox control.  When I call AddString, a MeasureItem message is sent asking me to tell Windows the size of the item.  The problem is, the code hasn't had a chance to call SetItemData yet, so the code can't determine the size yet.

I've tried calling SetRedraw(FALSE) hoping that would postpone the measure request, but no luck.

So how can I add an item to a CListBox and get the Item Data passed in at the same time?  I've tried with and without LBS_HASSTRINGS.  Not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your list box control does not have the `LBS_HASSTRINGS` style, the pointer argument to `AddString()` is not considered as a string but as item data (see the remarks section in the documentation for [LB_ADDSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775181.aspx)).

Therefore, if your list items consist in both a string and some item data, you can wrap these two pieces of information in a structure or a class and pass a pointer to that wrapper to `AddString()`.

The upside is that both the string and the item data will be available by the time `MeasureItem()` is called. The downside is that you will have to implement `CompareItem()` if your list is sorted, and to free the wrappers both when items are deleted and before the list box control is destroyed.

Comment: Fantastic -- I knew there had to be a trick in there somewhere :)